# Disable Autocomplete on space key in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How to disable auto completion on space key on Intellij

Problem: I always type "... = ". Mention the space after "=". The problem is that the auto completion popup comes immediately after inserting the "=" so pressing space as next key always applies first proposal.

> IntelliJ 2016.1.2

Comment: Are you referring to Ctrl + Space

Comment: @Marcel, did the above solution solved your problem?

Comment: @aman-tuladhar no. IntelliJ autocompletes on space. It just expanded an `else` to `EventLogSession` — which could not be more wrong.

Answer (score 19):

You can disable this by going to the preferences -> editor -> general -> code completion

There you should find a checkbox "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc. This you want to disable.

Now it will only complete on Ctrl+space, tab, enter, etc

Comment: Seems like this works only for "Show suggestions as you type" section.
So this checkbox is ignored if you get autocompletion menu by hands (e.g. with Alt + Space).

Comment: This is not the solution, as I would like to have other keys perform the task but space be excluded.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the same for a live template, it is under `preferences` -> `editor` -> `live templates` and you have a dropdown at the top

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, your answer prevented me setting fire to my desk. This behaviour of re-writing what I intentionally wanted to type drove me crazy for 1h and I could not find this damned setting anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work with the current version of Rider.

Answer (score 1):

This so late but I hope it will help someone.
go to preferences -> editor -> general -> code completion
locate and unselect this checkbox "White space inserts selected suggestions when completing popup is focused".

Checkbox Image:

[image: Checkbox Image:]

Now auto completion should work on Enter and Tab but not Space.